# Ranking em percentis - R

Tags: r

preciso dividir uma série temporal em 20 percentis igualmente espaçados e criar um ranking para essa divisão, classificando em níveis a volatilidade implícita, no caso.

A série temporal é composta por dados diários de 2011 a 2019, e os percentis serão construídos num período anual, então, eu vou observar um valor no momento *t* e classificá-lo de acordo com 20 percentis definidos a partir da série histórica de 1 ano anterior a data *t* e se esse valor em *t* for maior que o maior valor observado no ano anterior, seria criada uma categoria 21, para indicar nível altíssimo.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, poste na pergunta o que você já tentou até agora e qual é a sua dúvida da forma mais clara possível.

Comment: Oi, Filipe! Preciso descobrir como criar esse ranking dos percentis num período de 1 ano. eu comecei a usar o R há pouco, então, pra essa parte da dissertação, eu não faço nem ideia de como começar :S

Answer (score 0):

Para criar os 20 percentis igualmente espaçados podemos usar a função `seq()`. Após isso podemos usar a função `quantile()` para dizer os valores referentes aos percentis que definimos.

```r
percentis <- seq(0.05, 1, length.out = 20)
percentis
#>  [1] 0.05 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25 0.30 0.35 0.40 0.45 0.50 0.55 0.60 0.65 0.70
#> [15] 0.75 0.80 0.85 0.90 0.95 1.00

set.seed(123)
serie_temporal <- rnorm(1000)
quantile(serie_temporal, percentis)
#>           5%          10%          15%          20%          25% 
#> -1.622584310 -1.267328289 -1.049677448 -0.788690220 -0.628324243 
#>          30%          35%          40%          45%          50% 
#> -0.486452454 -0.348884728 -0.214854912 -0.097388721  0.009209639 
#>          55%          60%          65%          70%          75% 
#>  0.127070557  0.242040647  0.373732181  0.513088142  0.664601867 
#>          80%          85%          90%          95%         100% 
#>  0.841412710  1.019321461  1.254751947  1.676133871  3.241039935
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>